# Why are several signal numbers architecture-dependent on Linux?

Tags: linux, signals

Why are several signal numbers architecture-dependent on Linux?

Here is a quote along with a list of signals and signal numbers from `man 7 signal`:

> Linux supports the standard signals listed below.  **Several signal numbers are architecture-dependent**, as  indicated  in  the
>      "Value"  column. [...] Where three values are given, the first one is usually valid for alpha and sparc, the middle one for x86,
>      arm, and most other architectures, and the last one for mips.

```
Signal     Value
──────────────────
SIGHUP        1
SIGINT        2
SIGQUIT       3
SIGILL        4
SIGABRT       6
SIGFPE        8
SIGKILL       9
SIGSEGV      11
SIGPIPE      13
SIGALRM      14
SIGTERM      15
SIGUSR1   30,10,16
SIGUSR2   31,12,17
SIGCHLD   20,17,18
SIGCONT   19,18,25
SIGSTOP   17,19,23
SIGTSTP   18,20,24
SIGTTIN   21,21,26
SIGTTOU   22,22,27
```

Comment: Very interesting observation. I see that for Alpha, the kernel source has a comment: "Linux/AXP has different signal numbers that Linux/i386: I'm trying to make it OSF/1 binary compatible, at least for normal binaries" If it's all for binary compatibility, I would love to know which OS it is and how binary compatibility works when running on Linux

Comment: @thatotherguy Tru64 Unix... is what would normally run on an Alpha. In the case of Sparc, it probably has the same values on Solaris (which has heritage with AT&T SRV4 Unix... which Tru64 probably also shares), MIPS running IRIX is probably just being weird like Linux.

Answer (score 1):

They are arbitrary numbers unless you are wanting to be compatible with something else.

Namely Tru64 Unix for Alpha. Solaris for Sparc, they probably get these numbers from AT&T Unix SRV4 directly....

And IRIX for MIPS.... is just being weird like Linux.

Linux has it's own numbers for backwards compatibility with itself.